# How to Extract text, Without Extract All text?

Tags: html, imacros

How to copy text only **TEST DRIVING 1**?

**Example Source HTML :**

```
<div class="descr">
    <div class="marg5px" style="outline: 1px solid blue;">
    <a href="http://TEST-HTML.COM" title="TEST DRIVING 1">TEST DRIVING 1</a>
    <br>
    Grab all the stars and avoid spikes as you grab keys and activate your shield.
    <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

My iMacros Code:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:marg5px EXTRACT=TXT
 SET !CLIPBOARD {{!EXTRACT}}
```

This code works, but the result shows unwanted text

[image]

The result I want is, just the words `TEST DRIVING 1' as in the following picture:

[image]

Please give me suggestion code to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, sorry for late answer

TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:MARG5px 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TITLE* EXTRACT=TXT